# Please how can i fix this?

Tags: heroku

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqdD.png][1]

[No default language could be detected for this app.][2]

Hello,

I have a problem on my git hoping you can help me this is an error (No default language could be detected for this app.) And I have no idea how to handle this problem. I did it all on the internet, but nothing clear. Thanking you, can you orient me please?

LITTLE NOTE

the procfile file and the requirements file had some sort of? on it and were not which clickable. So I transformed them into a textmate file by going through: right click, Override File type puire Textmate. Besides, are File text and File textmate really different?

Windows 10 64bit

Comment: [An image of your exception is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`

also you should name the requirements file `requirements.txt` and it should auto detect

Comment: please mark as correct answer if it helped you